# Does there exist a Graph Counting Lemma in the Cut density condition?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

**Background:** In http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2011.03.011 Lem9.3 Svante Janson proved that let $0<p<1$ and graphon $W$ with $\int W=p$, if for any subset $A\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ it holds $\int_{A\times\left[0,1\right]/A} W=p|A|\times|\left[0,1\right]/A|$ then $W=p$ a.e. Thus for any graph $H:t(H,W)=p^{e(H)}$

**Question:** Does this right: let $0<p<1$ and $k\geq 1$ be constant and graphon $W$ with $\int W=kp$, if for any subset $A\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ it holds $\int_{A\times\left[0,1\right]/A} W\geq p|A|\times|\left[0,1\right]/A|$ then for any graph $H:t(H,W)\geq p^{e(H)}$.